# Unsure how to solve first-order Markov Chain problem

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

I am working on solving the following problem (I am new to Markov Chains):

-It can be either rainy or sunny on a given day.
-The probability that a rainy day is followed by a rainy day is 0.5. 
-The probability that a sunny day is followed by a sunny day is 0.3.

What is the percentage of days we can expect it to be rainy, asymptotically?

I created the transition matrix:

```
                 Rainy today|Sunny today
Rainy tomorrow    0.5       | 0.7
Sunny tomorrow    0.5       | 0.3
```

I used the joint probability formula like this P(rainy)=0.5*0.7 but this answer does not seem correct.

I hope someone can guide me and tell me what I am not doing correctly here.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to find the stationary distribution of a Markov chain?

Comment: @angryavian I was not aware I did find the stat. dist. Given the information above do you have any other way of approaching?

Comment: What I mean is that the question is asking you to find the stationary distribution of this Markov chain, which is the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$ of the transition matrix. (Whether it is a left- or right-eigenvector will depend on how you write your transition matrix.)

Comment: @angryavian how would you solve the problem with your approach? Again, I am very new to this topic and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Your transition matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.7 & 0.3 \end{bmatrix}$. (Traditionally, "today" labels the rows, and "tomorrow" labels the columns.)
You are looking for a vector $\begin{bmatrix}\mu_r & \mu_s \end{bmatrix}$ such that
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mu_r & \mu_s \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.7 & 0.3 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}\mu_r & \mu_s \end{bmatrix}.$$
Such a vector represents the stationary distribution, with $\mu_r$ being the limiting probability of rain.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you for the comment. Which formula do I need to apply in the last step to answer the question?

Comment: The equation there is a system of two equations with two unknowns, which you can solve.